# How do I include the Livecode Message Box in my stack?

Tags: livecode

I have a stack which was originally built in Hypercard then migrated to Metacard.  Obviously, it has expanded greatly over that time.  Some core features broke when I tried to migrate to Runrev which is why I've waited till now to finally do that.  I'm keeping it as a stack rather than an exe so I can save changes to it.  I've built a standalone player to launch it and that is working.  I've included the revmessagebox.rev stack in the Standalone Stack settings.  This does add it but, incorrectly.  I can put messages to it from my stack but, it won't run commands and it's missing all it's icons.  I'm also included the revimagelibrary.rev and revtools.rev stacks in the hopes of fixing this but, no dice.  I was also hoping that including revimagelibrary.rev would get my old Metacard icons to display but, no dice.  I appreciate any help I can get on this.
Rich

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. The message box is part of the IDE and requires the development environment to run. When you build a standalone your scripts etc are compiled and an interpreter for commands is no longer present.
To replicate it in a standalone you could use a simple window with a field to accept text and would require you passing the text entered to a "Do" command. The other functions present with the message box (accessed via the icons you mentioned) are also development tools and don't make much sense in a standalone.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  All I need is something to display messages and occasionally execute a line of script for diagnostic purposes.  If I roll my own, is there a catch-all method for directing all the put statements in my stack to my newly minted message box?

Answer (score 2):

The message box is not only integrated into the IDE, the engine also has hooks that directly support it. I'm not sure those hooks are included with the engine that is built into a standalone, so even if you adapt the existing message box for your standalone it still may not work correctly.

The solution, as others have said, is to build your own stack that functions as a pseudo-message box. It is easy to display messages in your own stack, and pretty easy to execute simple commands using the "do" command. It is somewhat more difficult to execute complex or multi-line commands. But I agree with Dunbarx that I'd assess the need for such a thing if you are planning this standalone for distribution. It's a non-standard interface element.

Answer (score 0):

What James said. But note that though the msg box is indeed integral to the IDE, it is still just a stack, and that stack can be replicated to whatever extent you need.

That said, the msg box is usually used as a development tool, to test short scripts (usually one-liners), to get or set property values quickly, as a simple calculator, that sort of stuff. If you need that sort of functionality, you should probably integrate it more comprehensively into the structure of your project.

Craig Newman